# Drawing Labels using TextPath inside a donut chart

Tags: d3.js

I am looking for a jsfiddle sample for a donut chart in D3, where

- labels are inside the arcs
- labels are centerd inside each arc
- they are bended over the arc (like the figure below)

**Update**: Here is my code so far http://jsfiddle.net/gs5qp5sx/1/

```
svg.selectAll("text").data(dataset.apples).enter()
        .append("text")
        .style("font-size",15)
        .style("fill","#F8F8F8")
        .attr("dy",0)
        .append("textPath")
        .attr("xlink:href",function(d,i){return "#s"+i;})
        .attr("startOffset","50%")
        .style("text-anchor","middle")
        .text(function(d,i){return "label"+i;})
```

[image]

Do you know any sample that does this ?

Comment: Create jsfiddle using what you tried, and post here so other can find solution using that.

Comment: [This demo](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2565344) may help.

Answer (score 0):

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887193

http://www.kevlindev.com/tutorials/basics/text/svg/index.htm

hope this samples help you!.